# Vue v-bind:class doesn't work on default truthiness check

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a simple `v-bind:class` like this: `<div v-bind:class="{ showBranding: brandingEnabled }">BRANDING</div>`

In my data, `brandingEnabled` is true and can be changed to false. Changing it to false does no remove the class.

It works perfect if I do this:  `<div v-bind:class="{ showBranding: (brandingEnabled == 'true') }">BRANDING</div>`

Could this be an issue with my booleans being treated as strings? I have tried setting them (in my Vue data) to true, rather than "true" but that doesn't change anything either.

I have also tried setting the data to type: Boolean via props but to no avail.

I would really rather have it working with the simple syntax if possible...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It should work, the VueJs documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html clearly mentions that. Can you post your code here or in JS fiddle?

Comment: If `showBranding` class is `display:none` your doing it wrong, use `v-if="brandingEnabled"` instead.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, the class does more than that. I gave your suggestion a go though and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think the key thing here is that `<div v-bind:class="{ showBranding: (brandingEnabled == 'true') }">BRANDING</div>` works perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

If showBranding is a CSS class, you have to add single quote around your css className, like this:

```
<div :class={'showBranding': brandingIsEnabled}>
// content
</div>
```

Then your class has to be inside a style tag into your component like this:

```
<style scoped>
 .showBranding {
   // content
 }
</style>
```

Check also if your brandingIsEnabled data is inside your script tag like this:

```
<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
    brandingIsEnabled: true       
   }
  } 
 }
</script>
```

This example uses the single component syntax.

Comment: Do I have to have everything on the page within tags like that. Can't I pull in my JS and CSS from files? I am using Vue with Laravel. I don't think that is the issue as when I check fully like this: `<div v-bind:class="{ showBranding: (brandingEnabled == 'true') }">BRANDING</div>`, it works perfectly...

Answer (score -2):

```
new Vue({
        el: '#br',
        data: {
            showBranding: 'brandingClass',
            brandingEnabled:true
        }

    });
```

---

CSS Code

```
.brandingClass{
  display:none
}
```

---

html code

```
<div id="br">
    <div :class="{ showBranding:brandingEnabled }">BRANDING</div>
</div>
```